# Laravel return Csrf error as json

Tags: validation, laravel, mobile, token, csrf

I'm building a mobile app and when a CSRF token isn't present I want to return an error in JSON instead of it returning the "TokenMismatchException" Html page.

Is there anyway to do this easily without adjusting the library code?

Comment: If your client that calls your API sends the proper headers, Laravel will return this as a json response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create your own [custom responses](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/errors#render-method) and make one for TokenMismatchException

So you do that in the `Exceptions/Handler.php` file. Something *like*;

```
public function render($request, Exception $e)
{
    if($e instanceof TokenMismatchException)
    {
        return json(......
    }
```

I think you might also need to include in the use statement;

`use Illuminate\Session\TokenMismatchException as TokenMismatchException;`